# Make the Range HTML Input Type styles compatible across Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I have some code in which I style a range type input field, but it seems as though this style is not compatible with IE11.

**try.html**

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="container">
        <input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="100">
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
.slider{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 3px;
  opacity: 1;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border:3px solid #6452d6;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 55px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

I have managed to display the required design in Chrome, but this CSS does not seem to work with IE11. How can I make this display properly in IE11?

Comment: -webkit prefix is only for chrome and safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read my code carefully, You need to add MS filler.

```css
body {
    padding: 30px;
}
input[type=range] {
    /*removes default webkit styles*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    
    /*fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug */
    border: 1px solid white;
    
    /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
    width: 300px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
}

/*hide the outline behind the border*/
input[type=range]:-moz-focusring{
    outline: 1px solid white;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    
    /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
    background: transparent;
    
    /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 6px 0;

    /*remove default tick marks*/
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #888;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="container">
      <input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="100">
      </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

You need add MS fillers like this:

```
input[type=range]::-ms-track
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower
```

For more information you can go here [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brenna/f4uq9edL/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=f4uq9edL)

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Thank you so much sir You are right. this is it. Appreciate.

Comment: Sir thanks for your support but its "reputation" problem. My vote is casted but will never dsiplay publically. because my Reputation is less than 15 till now